# Creating drupal 6 module with tabs

Tags: drupal, tabs, drupal-modules

I'm creating a module that let's your users add feeds.
So i want my code to provide tabs that can be overwritten at the theme layer.

I thought this could be done with the hook_menu:

```
$items['tab_add_feed'] = array(
  'title' => 'Add Feed',
  'page callback' => 'xml_parser_add_feed',
  'access callback' => 'user_access',
  'access arguments' => array('manage own feeds'),
  'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
);
```

something like the above.
But I'm using it on the front side of the site.

How can i add tabs or links on top of my page the drupal way?

//edit

There are none tabs present at the moment, maybe i have to make them visible?

fixed it by adding `<a href="xml_parser/add_feed">add feed</a>` to the main page callback function
But this is ugly, hard coded and not theme-able. waiting for a better solution.

//edit

This is the code i am using now

```
function xml_parser_menu() {
    $items = array();

    $items['xml_parser'] = array(
            'path' => 'xml_parser',
            'title' => t('Feed'),
            'description' => t('Add/edit feeds'),
            'page callback' => 'xml_parser_manage_overview', 
            'access callback' => 'user_access', // get user access
            'access arguments' => array('manage own feeds'), // check user if premission is set
            'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
            'menu_name' => 'primary-links', // add to primary menu
    );

    $items['xml_parser/add_feed'] = array(
            'path' => 'xml_parser/add_feed',
            'title' => 'Add Feed',
            'page callback' => 'xml_parser_add_feed',
            'access callback' => 'user_access',
            'access arguments' => array('manage own feeds'),
            //'access' => user_access('maintain own subscriptions'),
            'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    );
    return $items;
}
```

Comment: in your code there is an error in the access arguments. this wants the value as array; 'access arguments' => array('manage own feeds'),

Comment: thnx, I've edited the code now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the name of the item would be something like 'user/%/add_feed', with the % argument being the user id. Also, the access callback is spelled incorrectly, should be user_access. This should create a tab for a user on the user profile page. You could also do node/%/add_feed to add a tab to a node.

While developing this module, you may find it useful to also use this:

```
function mymodule_init() {
   cache_clear_all();
   menu_router_build();
}
```

Until you get the menu straight.

If you want to just add an arbitrary tab to a page to add a feed, it would probably be an autonomous menu or a themed link. I would need to know more about the context of the feeds you are trying to provide and how users are subscribing.

Comment: I don't want to add a tab to a user or node page. I want to add a tab to 'my module page'. Also I've removed the typo's from my question

Comment: Oh, then you need a few more menu items. One to define the path of your module, then the tabs that will appear on it as local tasks.

Comment: What I mean to say is, in order to have tabs, they have to be nested under a parent item. I don't think you can have a root path and make it a local task.

Comment: so i have my module page not as root anymore. edited my question. still there is no 'tab' visible after i rebuild the menu.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add a tab to the front page.  Remember that the front page of your website is not really "/", it is "/node" by default (unless you changed it).

I'm just guessing because I haven't tried this, but your code *should* work if you change the key for your tab in $items to `node/tab_add_feed`.

If you have something else as your front page (ie. a view or panel), this would not apply.

Comment: so i changed the key and path (that's the same really? ) this is the way to say that it is a child of a parent item?  still it is not working